# Struggling reviving blog built on Wordpress (Bitnami), Lightsail, and Google Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ssl-certificate, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I had an operational and accessible Bitnami Wordpress site on Lightsail with my domain at GoDaddy. My cert expired so I went to renew it, and also switch my domain from living at GoDaddy to being at Google Domains. Ever since, I haven't been able to load the site by IP or domain. Are there any good guides specifically for configuring this set up?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Please ensure your domain points to the correct IP address (the one assigned to your instance). You can verify that using this online tool:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/

If the domain doesn't resolve to the correct IP address, you will need to update the DNS records in your DNS provider dashboard. Once you confirm everything is configured correctly, you should be able to renew your certificate.

Comment: Yes, the a record on whatsmydns.net returns the corresponding IP for my instance in Lightsail for most nameserver locations. But when I go to the site or IP, I get:
"This site can’t be reached 
xxxx refused to connect."

If it was configured properly, wouldn't it let me access the site with an insecure connection if I wanted?

Comment: If you get a refused to connect error message, it means that something is not working properly in the instance. Please confirm that Apache is started (sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status) and that there is not any error in the Apache's log file `sudo tail -n30 /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`.